No guarda los permisos para usar en mostrar los menús
Buenas a todo tengo un problema con un proyecto que es que al momento de llamar datos para iniciar en el login de un programa de ventas si los toma pero al momento de mostrar los menús me no me muestra nada y al momento de poner el punto de depuración me dice que no toma los permisos de mi consulta solo los datos de inicio
public partial class Inicio : Form
{
private static Usuario usuarioActual;
private static IconMenuItem MenuActivo = null;
private static Form FormularioActivo = null;
public Inicio(Usuario objusuario)

{
    usuarioActual = objusuario;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Permiso> ListaPermiso = new CN_Permiso().Listar(usuarioActual.IdUsuario);


    lblusuario.Text = usuarioActual.NombreCompleto;
}

específicamente en ListaPermiso deben estar guardados los permisos pero no es así.
ya verifique que las consultas estén bien ya comprobé que las palabras sean las mismas para todos los métodos pero no logro hacer que funcione.
capa de negocio
namespace CapaNegocio
{
public class CN_Permiso
{
    private CD_Permiso objcd_permiso = new CD_Permiso();
    public List<Permiso> Listar(int IdUsuario)
    {
        return objcd_permiso.Listar(IdUsuario);
    }
}
}

esta en mi capa de datos
 namespace CapaDatos
 {
 public class CD_Permiso
 {
    public List<Permiso> Listar(int IdPermiso)
    {
        List<Permiso> lista = new List<Permiso>();
        using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cadena))
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                query.AppendLine("p.IdRol, NombreMenu from PERMISO p");
                query.AppendLine("inner join ROL r on r.IdRol = p.IdRol");
                query.AppendLine("inner join USUARIO u on u.IdRol = r.IdRol");
                query.AppendLine("where u.IdUsuario = @IdUsuario");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), oconexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUsuario", IdPermiso);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                oconexion.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        lista.Add(new Permiso()
                        {
                            oRol = new Rol() { IdRol = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdRol"])},
                            NombreMenu = dr["NombreMenu"].ToString(),
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lista = new List<Permiso>();
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
}
}

